# Calculating integrals on matlab

Tags: matlab, integral

How can I calculate the volume of the integral

```
x = sqr(siny), 0<=y<=pi, X = 0, y = 4`
```

I know to plug in

```
int(sym('2*pi*sin(y)*exp(1/2)'),0,pi)
```

But I don't know how to set the bounds.

Comment: you set the bounds already ... `...0,pi)`.... `int(expr,var,a,b)` computes the definite integral of `expr` with respect to `var` from `a` to `b`

Comment: Im relativly new to mat lab. how would i graph this function to find the area of the integral?

Comment: `int` only finds the integral value.  Why would you need to graph this?

Comment: @rayryeng This question might be considered "too simple" or something like this, but we should not neglect it in my opinion. Similar questions pop up in masses every year, but the seldom get a simple answer or an answer at all. My point is that a good answer might indeed be helpful for the community.

Comment: @patrik I wasnt neglecting this in any way. I just wanted to know why a graph was required. Of course a good answer is welcome...  I think you just misinterpreted my question.

Comment: @rayryeng probably. It is a valid question though :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that an integral in Matlab works the same way as the integral operator does in maths there should be simple to solve. So in maths the expression

```
I = int(f(x),a,b),
```

calculates the integral between the closed bounds `[a,b]`. The Matlab equivalent is

```
syms x;
a = 0; % Example values
b = pi;
y = x^2;
I = int(y,0,pi); % I is a sym.
IDouble = eval(I);
```

So I is still a sym, but if you want the value as a double you can evaluate the expression with `eval` (which is not the same `eval` as is used for `eval('a=1;')`). However, the math expression

```
F(x) = int(f(x)),
```

calculates the *primitive function* or *indefinite integral*. The matlab equivalent of this is

```
syms x;
y = x^2;
Y = int(y);
```

where `Y` is the primitive function of `y`. This can then be plotted with the plot function for symbolic expressions `ezplot`. Try to plot above code with the command `ezplot(Y,-1,6);`. As for assuming Matlab automatically plots an integral after calculating it, you should not do that. Matlab is mainly created for complicated functions (maybe with no analytic solution or a too long or complicated solution to be able to do by hand). This means that the numerical/symbolic/plotted output may not necessarily be of interest. The interesting output may be the result of several complicated calculations and this may be the only output wanted. If Matlab by default subsequently generated plots for every step, this would be extremely annoying. It would also compromise the reputation Matlab tries to build being a general purpose programming language.